# Is there any ros node that allows to move shapes in RVIZ with a phantom omni device?

Tags: ros, markers.rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know if there is any ros node that allows to move shapes in RVIZ with a phantom omni device?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222110/is-there-any-ros-node-that-allows-to-move-shapes-in-rviz-with-a-phantom-omni-device-?/) by [masihec](https://answers.ros.org/users/24631/masihec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm unaware of something that provides this functionality out-of-the-box, but it would be trivial to write a node that accomplishes what you want. For example, if you use [@danepowell's phantom_omni](https://github.com/danepowell/phantom_omni) package, the driver publishes a `/joint_states` topic that contains the joint angles of the Omni. If you also start a [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) as seen in his [example launch file](https://github.com/danepowell/phantom_omni/blob/master/launch/omni_headless.launch) then the current geometric description of the Omni will be available via [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2). All you then have to do is write a ROS node that looks up the transform from a "control" frame on the Omni (e.g. the `/stylus` frame) to some reference frame (e.g. the `/base` frame). Using this transform data, you then can correspondingly move a [visualization_msgs/Marker](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) to represent your shape.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2